# Connect to Jupyter Notebook via ssh

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

I desire to edit my jupyter notebook python script created on a cluster on Watson Studio Cloud on my local machine through my emacs editor.

I know it is possible to do that and I was able to do so in other environments but not on Watson Studio Cloud. The issue is that I must connect to the script via ssh and I am not sure that Watson Studio Cloud offers the possibility to ssh into it.

Is anyone aware if it is possible to ssh in watson studio cloud? Any documentation on how to enable ssh mode and import the ssh-key?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, Watson Studio on Cloud does not offer the capability to ssh into your notebook runtimes. At the moment, the only way to access the runtimes is through the web UI.

`ssh` is installed in the runtimes. Maybe you could set up some kind of reverse tunnel by ssh-ing from inside the runtime to an ssh server operated by yourself?

Comment: I see.. interesting thought. Thank you very much.
Was not aware of the technique and I will give it a go. Sounds interesting.